# Python Django auto generating field not present in form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to django and I have a web application, in which I have an model called Template.
this model has one field called body and one field called tokens.
sample body would be : "I am {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}"
I want tokens field to be filled by comma separated values : "first_name, last_name"
so in admin form for creation and change I don't want to be asked for this field value.
how can I achieve this in django?
here is what I tried, which doesn't work.

```py
class SmsTemplate(models.Model):
    """ Message SMS Template """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    tokens = models.SlugField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            self.tokens = ",".join(re.findall(r'{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}', self.body))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

python 3.7.0

django 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove field from django admin page . There is an attribute `fields` in `admin.ModelAdmin` class. It will not show this field in admin page. Moreover, in save method of model you can remove if statement.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about ModelAdmin at all, I read about it, now I know what I have to do.
could you please tell me what this line is about ?

if self.pk is None:

Comment: In this save method `self` points to object which is created from current class. So it can be existed object(which exists in database and was taken using `SmsTemplate.objects.get(**kwargs) query`) or new object(which does not exists in database and created as `SmsTemplate(**kwargs)`).

Comment: First of all model class does not have field pk(it automatically translates pk into id field in query) at all. Secondly, if you want that your code works for both type objects(`self`) you should not add `if` statement. If you want that your code works only on creation you should add [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal.